# React component is updating late

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I am using `React.useEffect()` and the results are updating late. Why is that so ?

```js
function Process(props) {
  const [results, setResults] = React.useState({
    number: "",
    f: {}
  });

  let data = props.data; //returns object from another component which changes

  React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => setResults(data)
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <p>{results.number}</p> //ouputs previous number
  );
};
```

*Please tell me if you need the component which passes the `props={data}` to `Process()` component.*

Thanks

Comment: the return value of a useEffect function is a function that get's called to clean what the useEffect does, are you sure you want to call setResults at that moment and not directly in the body of the function? https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the return value of a useEffect function is a function that get's called to clean what the useEffect does

if you want to run the setResults as soon as `data` change, do that in the body of the function

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  setResults(data)
}, [data]);
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 1):

if `props.data` is already a useState there is no need for using another useEffect and useState, React already handles that and you can just use the value

```
function Process(props) {
   let data = props.data;

  return <p> { data.number } </p>
}
```